# Is it possible to run WatchKit app on Actual Apple Watch device?

Tags: debugging, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, xcode6.4

I am developing a WatchKit App in Xcode 6.4, and I have access to a real Apple Watch. It's possible to debug the WatchKit App on it?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Run the iOS app on the iPhone from Xcode

2) The iPhone app will be launch and watch app will be installed on the watch.

3) need to tap the watch app to launch it.

4) When I select **Debug -> Attach to process**

you can simply type the full and complete name of your process. if you don't know it, try ps -axww in terminal and try to find the process running there and paste the name into Xcode.